# Logs in exist in the AWS cloudwatch but does not return the logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is my code,  used with filterLogEvents function for filter the logs, but does not retun the logs.

```
let params = {
        logGroupName : 'xxxx',
        filterPattern: '{ $.notification.messageId = "d890f718-5f1a-5b1c-9694-a141de3101bs" }'
    };
    cloudWatchLogs.filterLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data.events);           // successful response
    });
```

And here is the response when running the function
[] (empty array. but logs is exists in the cloudwatch)

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1468

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy some logs are getting. but some logs are not getting.

Comment: This may be too specific to the amazon API to be discussed on stackoverflow, I recommend you contact them directly.

Comment: I've read somewhere that there can be a delay of up to 12 hours before logs are made available to export. This is not really an export but it is not impossible that it could be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you that try

```
await cloudWatchLogs.filterLogEvents(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data.events); // successful response
        }).promise();
```

Comment: Hi! Try to provide some insight on why do you think this is the solution ;)

Comment: Because, excessively relying on callbacks is bad in general not just in the context of a Lambda function. In response to that, I suggested this solution.
reference [async functions with lambda](https://advancedweb.hu/comparing-async-javascript-functions-and-callbacks-on-aws-lambda/) @zolastro